# How to get `max_length` in CharField's description in Django?

Tags: django

I am trying to get affordances of all the fields of a model. For which, I first fetch all the fields using `._meta_get_fields()` which returned an ImmutableList of fields, and then for each field, I used its `.description` attribute.

For different fields it returned,

- `BooleanField` : "Boolean (Either True or False)"
- `IntegerField` : "Integer"
- `DateTimeField` : "Date (with time)"
- `CharField` : "String (up to %(max_length)s)"

As you can see in the case of `CharField`, even though `max_length` is defined, Django isn't resolving that variable in CharField's description itself.

Comment: This makes sense since the form will perform *string interpolation* with the fields `__dict__`  on the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see in the case of `CharField`, even though `max_length` is defined, Django isn't resolving that variable in `CharField`'s description itself.

That is indeed the case. It would also not make much sense, since that would mean that if we later call `.deconstruct(…)` the original message is gone.

You can use string interpolation, for example with:

```
myfield = …  # the CharField
desc = myfield.description % myfield.__dict__
```

For example for a `CharField` we get:

```
>>> myfield.description % myfield.__dict__
'String (up to 128)'
```

This is specified in the [documetation of the **`description=…`** field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.description):

> The description can be of the form:
>
> ```
> description = _("String (up to %(max_length)s)")
> ```
>
> where the **arguments are interpolated from the field’s `__dict__`**.